# How to specify what "list" the product was added to cart from? Enhanced Ecommerce

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce, implementation, product

Trying to implement Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce tracking for my website.

**How to specify what "list" the product was added to cart from?**

Here is the standard tracking code for adding the product to basket:

```
    // Called when a product is added to a shopping cart.
function addToCart(product) {
  ga('ec:addProduct', {
    'id': product.id,
    'name': product.name,
    'category': product.category,
    'brand': product.brand,
    'variant': product.variant,
    'price': product.price,
    'quantity': product.qty
  });
  ga('ec:setAction', 'add');
  ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'add to cart');     // Send data using an event.
}
```

There is no any functionality to specify the name of the products list where the button "add to cart" was clicked.

There is must be something like this:

```
ga('ec:setAction', 'click', {'list': 'Search Results'});
```

but that works only for 'click' action, (not 'add'). (as per [https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#(product action)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#(product%20action)%20list) )

Moreover I need to specify position of product in a list.
**Any ideas?**

Comment: How is your "click" not the same as "add"? In other words, when you add a product to the cart, that requires a "click" action. Is that your implementation? Also, product data allows you to specify position: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-data.

Comment: nyuen, thank you for your comment.  "add" and "click" are different types of enhanced ecommerce actions in Google Analytics.  Click is all about when you click the product link and then viewing it's details page.  But "add" measures additions to shopping cart.  There is the difference...

Comment: The Google Docs are just wrong. And there is already a bug at [Google Analytics Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=product%20list&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=553).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List variable in actionField is only valid for **click** and **detail** action.
If you want to track the customer journey, you have to merge click and add into one logical event.

So If you can add directly from list and you want to tie data together in UA, you have do soem little workaround like:

```
function addToCart(product) {
  ga('ec:addProduct', {
    'id': product.id,
    'name': product.name,
    'category': product.category,
    'brand': product.brand,
    'variant': product.variant,
    'price': product.price,
    'quantity': product.qty    
  });
  ga('ec:setAction', 'click', {'list': 'Search Results'});
  ga('send', 'event', 'automatic', 'click', 'add to cart',{'nonInteraction': 1});     // Send data using an event.

  ga('ec:addProduct', {
    'id': product.id,
    'name': product.name,
    'category': product.category,
    'brand': product.brand,
    'variant': product.variant,
    'price': product.price,
    'quantity': product.qty
  });
  ga('ec:setAction', 'add');
  ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'add to cart');     // Send data using an event.
}
```

Comment: This answer is not 100% correct. You can `ga('ec:setAction', 'add', {'list': 'Search Results'});` - you have to track the click on product at product list on the product list page.

Comment: This answer is not correct, as mentioned above. There is no need for product clicks or product details to capture the list information, this can be added as an action field in the add to cart dataLayer push. I have tested this and the purchases were correctly attributed back to the list I set only in the add to cart dataLayer push.

Comment: @sdhaus is correct, this doesn't work but it works if you add it as an actionField.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was stuck for hours.

My issue was that I had the checkout process on a different subdomain than where the product impressions was listed and clicked on. 
By simply adding a field on the GA page view tag i GTM, `"cookieDomain" = "auto"`, all started working - [Cross Domain Tracking with Google Tag Manager](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/06/16/cross-domain-tracking-with-google-tag-manager/).

The only places I needed to add information about the list, was:

- product impressions list. `'list' : 'Search result'`
- product click (from impressions list). `'actionField': {'list': 'Search Results'},`

I did not add it for product detail, or anywhere in the checkout process (add to cart, checkout, purchase).

For other external domains in the checkout process I guess you will need cross domain tracking.

Answer (score 1):

There are three things you have to do.

**1. Track your product list click at your product list page**

```
/**
 * Binds click event on product detail page links at product list page.
 */
var bindProductListClickTracking = function() {
    jQuery('a.detail-link-track:not(.ga-click-bound)').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        //all my product data are attributes á la data-product-sku
        var product = jQuery('li[data-product-detail-link="' + href + '"]')[0];

        ga('ec:addProduct', {
            'id': product.dataset.productSku,
            'name': product.dataset.productName,
            'category':product.dataset.productCategory,
            'brand': product.dataset.productBrand,
            'variant': product.dataset.productVariant,
            'position': jQuery(product).index() + 1
        });

        var list = product.dataset.productList;
        /**
          * IMPORTANT: save your product list name into a cookie
          */
        jQuery.cookie('productlist', list, { path: '/', domain: cookieDomain});

        ga('ec:setAction', 'click', {list: list});

        ga('send', 'event', {
            eventCategory: 'productlist',
            eventAction: 'click',
            eventLabel: list,
            hitCallback: function () {
                if (!(e.ctrlKey || e.which == 2)) {
                    document.location = href;
                }
            }
        });
    }).addClass('ga-click-bound');
}
```

**Hint:** *If you have lazy loading or a load more button, be careful not to bind this event twice on your product detail page links.*

**2. Add actionObject for your product list to your add to cart action at your product detail page**

```
var manipulationOfCart = function(product, type, productList) {
    ga('ec:addProduct', {
        'id': product.id,
        'name': product.name,
        'category': product.category,
        'brand': product.brand,
        'variant': product.variant,
        'price': product.price,
        'quantity': product.qty
    });

    ga('ec:setAction', type, {list: productList});

    if (type == 'add') {
        ga('send', {
            hitType: 'event',
            eventCategory: 'Cart',
            eventAction: 'click',
            eventLabel: 'Add To Cart',
            nonInteraction: 1
        });
    } else if (type == 'remove') {
        ga('send', {
            hitType: 'event',
            eventCategory: 'Cart',
            eventAction: 'click',
            eventLabel: 'Remove From Cart',
            nonInteraction: 1
        });
    }
}
```

**3. Remove cookie after you added a product to your cart or user leaves product detail page**

```
manipulationOfCart(productToBasket, 'add', productlist);
$.removeCookie('productlist', { path: '/', domain: cookieDomain});
```

**AND**

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    $.removeCookie('productlist', { path: '/', domain: cookieDomain});
});
```

Actually the [Google Analytics Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-impression) are wrong - it does not work what they are saying. And there is already a bug reported at [Google Analytics Bug Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=553).

Answer (score 0):

You should send the `list` property when you add the `detail` action (which should be sent when a user views the product page).

`ga('ec:setAction', 'detail', { list: 'Search Results' });`

Consider the following scenario:

1. User searches on your website for a product, the results are displayed. At this point an impression is created for each product result.
2. The user clicks on one of the product results, you add a `click` action, and the user is then redirected to the product page.
3. Upon page load, you send a `detail` action, specifying the `list` property (as a parameter in `setAction`).
4. User clicks 'Add To Cart', and you send the `add` action.

If you don't specify the `list` property in the `detail` action, or don't send a `detail` action at all, and then call the `add` action, when viewing the data under **Product List Performance** in Analytics, the **Add To Cart** data will appear under **Product List Name** as **(not set)**.

The documentation fails to include this crucial piece of information in their complete example, which can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#example)